# Active-Passive Applications using DynamoDB locks

Tags: amazon-web-services, locking, amazon-dynamodb

I have a use case where I want to run my application in active-passive mode. Two instances will be running but only one will be active who acquires lock first while other will continuously wait for lock.

I am using Dynamodb tables in my project and I  want to implement locks based on dynamodb. I am not sure how it works.

Can someone help me to understand how this can be implemented using lock on dynamodb tables ?

Answer (score 0):

The feature in DynamoDB you are thinking about is Conditional Writes.  DynamoDB does not support "locking" natively, but you can use conditional writes to implement a lease or lock based system that should accomplish what you want by using DynamoDB.

The first thing to decide is if you want to implement a lease based system or a lock based system.  The primary difference being that a lease will automatically expire if it is not renewed within a certain period of time while a lock will never automatically expire.  Generally speaking, a lease has better characteristics under most circumstances when using a distributed system.  For example, if the master node dies the standby node will take over when the lease expires, but if it was a lock it would not take over until another system released the lock.

A lock based system can be viewed as a special case of a lease based system where the lease expiration is infinitely in the future so I'm going to describe how you would implement a lease based system in DynamoDB.

---

The way you would implement lease system in DynamoDB is to have a table that will have records where each one represents a different lease.  The table design could look something like this:

- leaseId (Hash Key)
- resourceId (only set if the lease is assigned with who is holding it)
- leaseExpiration (only set if the lease is assigned; time stamp when the lease will expire)

The above design assumes that the resources known the leaseId that they are attempting to control.

The following algorithm outlines what actions are required by the server to obtain a :

```
if (not holding lease) then
  read record from DynamoDB using leaseId

  if (resourceId is not set) then
    # lease appears to be available

    perform conditional write on leaseId record
    # set resourceId to our ID and leaseExpiration to time in future
    # with condition that resourceId and leaseExpiration are not set

    if (conditional write succeeds) then
      # we have the lease!
      return true
    else
      # failed to get the lease
      return false
    done
  else if (leaseExpiration is past)
    # lease has expired so lets attempt to take it

    perform conditional write on leaseId record
    # set resourceId to our ID and leaseExpiration to time in future
    # with condition that resourceId and leaseExpiration were values we read earlier

    if (conditional write succeeds) then
      # we have the lease!
      return true
    else
      # failed to get the lease
      return false
    done

  done
else
  # we have the lease, so lets keep it

  perform conditional write on leaseId record

  # set leaseExpiration to time in future
  # with condition that resourceId is equal to our ID

  if (conditional write succeeds) then
    # we still have the lease!
    return true
  else
    # we lost our lease
    return false
  done

done
```

If the entire server is what is being protected then the above algorithm is essentially run in a loop.  If the resource has the lease then it needs to run before the lease expires to ensure it keeps it.  If the resource does not have the lease it should wait a bit before attempting to get it again.

If the server wants to give up the lock then it would execute the following algorithm:

```
perform conditional write on leaseId record
# erase resourceId and erase leaseExpiration attributes
# with condition that resourceId is equal to our ID

if (conditional write succeeds) then
  # we successfully gave up the lease
else
  # the lease was not ours to give up
done
```